# PHP: Why is the flag SORT_LOCALE_STRING not working as expected?

Tags: php, sorting, utf-8, localization

My code - short and easy:

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL,'de_DE');
    $tosort = ["Österreich","Indien","Deutschland","Vereinigtes Königreich","Zimbabwe"];
    asort($tosort,SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
    var_dump($tosort);
```

Result:

> array(5) { [2]=> string(11) "Deutschland" [1]=> string(6) "Indien"
>   [3]=> string(23) "Vereinigtes Königreich" [4]=> string(8) "Zimbabwe"
>   [0]=> string(11) "Österreich" }

Expected Result:

> array(5) { [2]=> string(11) "Deutschland" [1]=> string(6) "Indien"
>   [3]=> string(11) "Österreich"[4]=> string(23)  "Vereinigtes Königreich" 
>   [0]=> string(8) "Zimbabwe" }

Docs: http://php.net/manual/de/function.sort.php

Problem: The string is not sorted locally, even though I specifically did setlocale before the sorting. What is going wrong here and how might I solve this? The Ö Umlaut is expected to come directly between the O in the alphabet. What might go wrong here?

Comment: I modified the example in the duplicate and it produced what you were asking for https://3v4l.org/ScXfi

Comment: Also, the `Ö` is a much higher UTF-8 character number than A-Z. That's why it appears last in a basic sort

Comment: Ok thank you. The Collator seems to throw a fatal error if on PHP 7.0.1 I guess that has something to do with the PHP intl package? http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php

Comment: Looks like it is a separate package in most distros. [The comments on the install page should help you get the right package](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php)